# (Spring) Kafka appears to consume newly produced messages out of order

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

#### Situation:

We have a Spring Boot / Spring Kafka application that is reading from a Kafka topic with a single partition.  There is a single instance of the application running and it has a single-threaded `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` (not `Concurrent`).  We have a single consumer group.

We want to manage offsets ourselves based on committing to a transactional database.  At startup, we read initial offsets from our database and seek to that offset and begin reading older messages.  (For example with an empty database, we would start at offset 0.)  We do this via implementing `ConsumerRebalanceListener` and `seek()`ing in that callback.  We `pause()` the `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` prior to starting it so that we don't read any messages prior to the `ConsumerRebalanceListener` being invoked (then we `resume()` the container inside the `ConsumerRebalanceListener.onPartitionsAssigned()` callback).  We acknowledge messages manually as they are consumed.

#### Issue:

While in the middle of reading these older messages (1000s of messages and 10s of seconds/minutes into the reading), **a separate application produces messages into the same topic and partition we're reading from.**

We observe that these **newly produced messages are consumed immediately**, intermingled with the older messages we're in the process of reading.  So we observe message offsets that jump in this single consumer thread: from the basically sequential offsets of the older messages to ones that are from the new messages that were just produced, and then back to the older, sequential ones.

We don't see any errors in reading messages or anything that would trigger retries or anything like that.  The reads of newer messages happen in the `main` thread as do the reads of older messages, so I don't believe there's another listener container running.

**How could this happen?**  Doesn't this seem contrary to the ordering guarantees Kafka is supposed to provide?  How can we prevent this behavior?

#### Details:

We have the following settings (some in properties, some in code, please excuse the mix):

```
properties.consumer.isolationLevel = KafkaProperties.IsolationLevel.READ_COMMITTED
properties.consumer.maxPollRecords = 500
containerProps.ackMode = ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL
containerProps.eosMode = ContainerProperties.EOSMode.BETA 
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=none
spring.kafka.enable-auto-commit=false
```

Versions:
Spring Kafka 2.5.5.RELEASE
Kafka 2.5.1

(we could definitely try upgrading if there was a reason to believe this was the result of a bug that was fixed since then.)

I can share some code snippets for any of the above if it's interesting.

Comment: What you are suggesting sounds impossible. `>The reads of newer messages happen in the main thread as do...`. That is suspicious, the listener will only be called by the container thread; nothing should happen on the `main` thread. Are you handing off records to another thread via an executor or something else? Your listener code will be helpful.

Comment: can you confirm if compaction is enabled in the topic? if so, probably it is the reason you are getting this behaviour  because the messages you are sending have the same key, hence the new one will replace the old one.